# In my template vertical menubar is there i want it would be hide while page load

Tags: javascript

I used only for hide and show but not for page load

I want on onclick event it would be enabled or disabled and on page load it would be hide..

```js
function openNav() {
  document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "15%";
}

function closeNav() {
  document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "0";
}
```

```css
sidenav {
  height: 100%;
  width: 15%;
  position: fixed;
  background-color: #4682B4;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  transition: 0.5s;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-sm-2">
  <div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav">
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()"><i class="fa fa-times-circle" style="font-size:16px;color:white"></i></a>

    <div class="menus">
      <a href="#">About</a>
      <a href="#">Services</a>
      <a href="#">Clients</a>
      <a href="#">Contact</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <span style="font-size:30px;cursor:pointer" onclick="openNav()">&#9776;</span>
</div>
```

please help with page load script...

Comment: Welcome to SO! Share better code, the provided is not sufficient to answer. Also, provide a code with use of `angularJS`  or remove that tag, if not applicable

Comment: Post your html code or error you got

Comment: Did you mean preloader?

Comment: you can set initial width to '0' using css, javascript will do the rest :D

Comment: i have provide html code and css also, i want that div class sidenav would be disabled while page load and enabled onclick event

Comment: Are you using any preloader?

Comment: It works with initial width to '0'. thanks akhil

Comment: no i am not using any preloader...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly you want

```
#mySidenav{
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

and after load

```
document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.visibility= "visibile";
```

This would hide the sidenav while loading and show it after loading.